# What am I doing wrong around adding an additional case class constructor which first transforms it parameters?

Tags: scala, constructor, tuples, case-class

So, I had a very simple case class:

```
case class StreetSecondary1(designator: String, value: Option[String])
```

This was working just fine. However, I kept having places where I was parsing a single string into a tuple which was then used to build an instance of this case class:

```
def parse1(values: String): StreetSecondary1 = {
  val index = values.indexOf(" ")
  StreetSecondary1.tupled(
    if (index > -1)
      //clip off string prior to space as designator and optionally use string after space as value
      (values.take(index), if (values.size > index + 1) Some(values.drop(index + 1)) else None)
    else
      //no space, so only designator could have been provided
      (values, None)
  )
}
```

So, I wanted to refactor all the different places with this same parsing code into the case class like this (but this won't compile):

```
case class StreetSecondary2(designator: String, value: Option[String]) {
  def this(values: String) = this.tupled(parse(values))
  private def parse(values: String): (String, Option[String]) = {
    val index = values.indexOf(" ")
    if (index > -1)
      //clip off string prior to space as designator and optionally use string after space as value
      (values.take(index), if (values.size > index + 1) Some(values.drop(index + 1)) else None)
    else
      //no space, so only designator could have been provided
      (values, None)
  }
}
```

It appears there is some chicken/egg problem around adding a case class constructor AND having a function that takes the parameter(s) and transforms them prior to calling the actual constructor. I have fiddled with this (going on many tangents). I then resorted to trying the companion object pathway:

```
object StreetSecondary3 {
  private def parse(values: String): (String, Option[String]) = {
    val index = values.indexOf(" ")
    if (index > -1)
      //clip off string prior to space as designator and optionally use string after space as value
      (values.take(index), if (values.size > index + 1) Some(values.drop(index + 1)) else None)
    else
      //no space, so only designator could have been provided
      (values, None)
  }
  def apply(values: String): StreetSecondary3 = {
    val tuple: (String, Option[String]) = parse(values)
    StreetSecondary3(tuple._1, tuple._2)  //Why doesn't .tupled method work here?
  }
}
case class StreetSecondary3(designator: String, value: Option[String])
```

What am I doing wrong in StreetSecondary2? Is there some way to get it to work? Surely there has to be a better simpler way where I am not required to add all the companion object boilerplate present in StreetSecondary3. Is there?

Thank you for any feedback and guidance you can give me around this.

---

**UPDATE**

Whew! Lots of lessons learned already.

A) the StreetSecondary2 parse method does not use the "this" implicit context in the case class instance being constructed (i.e. it is a static method in Java terms), so it works better moved to the companion object.

B) Unfortunately when composing an explicit companion object for a case class, the compiler provided "implicit companion object" is lost. The tupled method (and others, I am guessing - sure wish there was a way to keep it and augment as opposed to blowing it away) were contained in the compiler provided "implicit companion object" and not provided in the new explicit companion object. This was fixed by adding "extends ((String, Option[String]) => StreetSecondary)" to the explicit companion object.

C) Here's an updated solution (which also incorporates a more terse version of the parse function with a nod of thanks to Gabriele Petronella):

```
object StreetSecondary4 extends ((String, Option[String]) => StreetSecondary4) {
  private def parseToTuple(values: String): (String, Option[String]) = {
    val (designator, value) = values.span(_ != ' ')
    (designator, Option(value.trim).filter(_.nonEmpty))
  }
  def apply(values: String): StreetSecondary4 =
    StreetSecondary4.tupled(parseToTuple(values))
}
case class StreetSecondary4(designator: String, value: Option[String])
```

This is barely better in terms of boilerplate than the StreetSecondary3 version. However, it now makes quite a bit more sense due to so much implicit context having now been made explicit.

Comment: Personally, I think the companion object way is the way to go.  Pairing a companion with a case class and using `apply` to perform some more complex construction of the case class seems a pretty natural solution.

Comment: I tried to call `tupled` on `this` in a case class and was unable to. Could this be your problem?

Comment: There are certain restrictions with auxiliary constructors.  It seems that all they can do is call another `this` variant, and this needs to be the first (and only line), and you can't do things like `this.tupled`.  That's why this stuff is better suited to be done in a companion where you won't have those restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hit on a language restriction on auxiliary constructors

> In Scala, every auxiliary constructor must invoke another constructor of the same class as its first action. In other words, the first statement in every auxiliary constructor in every Scala class will have the form this(. . . ). The invoked constructor is either the primary constructor (as in the Rational example), or another auxiliary constructor that comes textually before the calling constructor. The net effect of this rule is that every constructor invocation in Scala will end up eventually calling the primary constructor of the class. The primary constructor is thus the single point of entry of a class.
>
> If you’re familiar with Java, you may wonder why Scala’s rules for constructors are a bit more restrictive than Java’s. In Java, a constructor must either invoke another constructor of the same class, or directly invoke a constructor of the superclass, as its first action. In a Scala class, only the primary constructor can invoke a superclass constructor. The increased restriction in Scala is really a design trade-off that needed to be paid in exchange for the greater conciseness and simplicity of Scala’s constructors compared to Java’s.

([Programming in Scala, chapter 6, section 7](http://books.google.it/books?id=MFjNhTjeQKkC&lpg=PA103&ots=FMlmWKIOms&dq=In%20Scala%2C%20every%20auxiliary%20constructor%20must%20invoke%20another%20constructor&pg=PA103#v=onepage&q=In%20Scala,%20every%20auxiliary%20constructor%20must%20invoke%20another%20constructor&f=false))

Therefore you cannot call `this.tupled` as the first statement of your auxiliary constructor.

Adding the constructor in the companion object is definitely the way to go in this case.

---

Not relevant to the question itself, but you can greatly simplify your `parse` method using `span`

```
private def parse(values: String): (String, Option[String]) = {
  val (designator, value) = values.span(_ != ' ')
  (designator, Option(value.trim).filter(_.nonEmpty))
} //                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  //                              returns None if the string is empty
```

Comment: So, there is no way to use a tuple to construct a case class from within a case class constructor (without using the companion object). For example, instead of "... = this.tupled(parse(values))", using "... = this(parse(values))" where it implicitly calls the tupled method?

Comment: And any idea why the tupled method does not work in the companion object method where I had to write "StreetSecondary3(tuple._1, tuple._2)" instead of "StreetSecondary3.tupled(tuple)"?

Comment: In answer to my second commment question about the tupled method not working in the companion object, it's a known issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/jyWBMz5Qslw

Comment: Finally figured out the answer to my first comment question. I address it explicitly in the Update to my original question post above.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would use trait and companion object.

```scala
trait StreetSecondary1 {
  def designator: String
  def value: Option[String]
}

object StreetSecondary1 {
  // For `StreetSecondary1("str", Some("val"))`
  def apply(d: String, v: Option[String]): StreetSecondary1 =
    new StreetSecondary1 {
      val designator = d
      val value = v
    }

  // For `StreetSecondary1("raw")
  def apply(raw: String): StreetSecondary1 = {
    val (d, v) = parse(raw)
    apply(d, v)
  }

  private def parse(values: String): (String, Option[String]) = {
    val index = values.indexOf(" ")
    if (index > -1)
      //clip off string prior to space as designator and optionally use string after space as value
      (values.take(index), if (values.size > index + 1) Some(values.drop(index + 1)) else None)
    else
      //no space, so only designator could have been provided
      (values, None)
  }
}
```

Comment: Your method seems to add even more boilerplate than I had in my StreetSecondary3 solution.

Comment: Mixing case class and companion object can hit other limitation, as those for extractor/unapply. That's not the case for trait/object.

Comment: I have just written an Update to my original question addressing the tupled confusion. Can you tell if the extractor/unapply functionality is returned due to my now properly extending the companion object with the same function that was being used by the compiler on the implicit companion object?